# About CSS pre-processors

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i just started learning Web development .i learnt HTML 5 C S S 3 JavaScript Bootstrap 4 angular 2 but i came across few articles where people suggested to learn

cs pre-processors as well..but are they required ? if so which one is best along with bootstrap. stylus or less or sass.

Comment: IMO, no you don't need to learn about CSS preprocessors. They help with creating CSS, but only once you've learnt some CSS already. Then pre-processors can become a useful tool to help generate CSS.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Pre-Processors are not required, but they are a very helpful tool if you are working a lot with CSS, specially for large projects.

If you want to try a CSS Pre-Processor, it doesn't have much importance which one you choose, because all of them are very similar and you can easily jump from one to other.

I started with [less](http://lesscss.org/), but recently I jumped to [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (using SCSS syntax) without having to learn different things, just some features changes its syntax a little bit, nothing relevant.

Because you are learning Bootstrap 4 and it is built in SCSS, I recommend you to start with SASS. Moreover, SASS is the most popular Pre-Processor these days.

Keep in mind that you will probably need knowledge of other tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) in order to work with CSS Pre-Processors.